# nutch configuration for multiple solr cores

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.9 and Solr 4.10 on Linux. I need to crawl and index the content of a big website and would like to do this using separate Solr cores. The below is Nutch configuration as part of a cronjob...

```
./bin/crawl conf/core0urls crawl http://solrhost:8085/solr/core0 1
./bin/crawl conf/core1urls crawl http://solrhost:8085/solr/core1 2
```

I have a cronjob set up for one minute for the above. Could someone help me on the below...

1. I want to know for `core0` what does `1` mean and for `core1` what does `2` mean?
2. I have created separate `seed.txt` files using `conf/core0urls` and `conf/core1urls`. That works, but i want to have separate `regex-urlfilter.txt`  files for each core and Nutch should detect it. Please let me know how I can achieve it.
3. If the above is not possible in single Nutch, should I set up separate Nutch instances for each Solr core?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two instances of nutch to push to different solr cores (or servers for that matter). The issue is that you want to use different **regex-urlfilter.txt** files. Technically, you can do that using a single nutch instance, but it requires you to write a lot of code. Therefore, the shortest and easiest way is to set up two nutch instances.

With regards to the crawl command arguments,

```
./bin/crawl conf/core0urls crawl http://solrhost:8085/solr/core0 1
```

The **1** value here means crawl urls in **core0urls** only. Do not go to the second depth and crawl urls generated from the first crawl. Basically, you are lunching one crawl.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

1>
So reconfriming if i have setup /nutch/nutchcore0 so copy all the files from here and create /nutch/nutchcore1

in the cronjob

cd /nutch/nutchcore0
/bin/crawl conf/core0urls crawl http://solrhost:8085/solr/core0 1

cd /nutch/nutchcore1
./bin/crawl conf/core1urls crawl http://solrhost:8085/solr/core1 1
2>

 so for 1 value still have few questions does this mean 

so if in conf/core0urls/seed.txt
i have 
http://aaa.com
http://bbb.com
http://ccc.com


then it will crawl only http://aaa.com and it will not crawl other website http://bbb.com or http://ccc.com

Comment: You are right in number 1. However, for number 2, it will crawl all urls. However, it will not crawl links that were found in aaa.com, bbb.com or ccc.com. It you have set crawling depth to 2, then it will crawl these links also. Would mind to accept my answer or vote for it if you found it useful.

Comment: reconfirming  if set 1 it will only crawl aaa.com ,bbb.com,ccc.com .So you mean if i set 2 it will crawl all links found in the above urls. Are there any other values like 3,4,... what does that fine.

Comment: Nutch works by crawling urls then extracts links from crawled sites and puts them for the next crawl. In the next crawl, it will extract the links from new crawled sites and put them again in the next crawl. So, it is breath first crawling. It keeps extracting urls and crawling them. The deeper is your limit the more urls and crawl contents you will get.